# Does iOS libSDL 2.012 require bluetooth confirmation?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, sdl-2, ios-bluetooth, gamecontroller

I just updated SDL to 2.012 for my game-app and it seems my game is now required to ask for permission at start, as SDL looks for Bluetooth GameControllers?
Is there any way to get around this confirmation?